# Video file is corrupted while saving mp4 to external storage in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentprovider, android-external-storage

I am trying to save an mp4 file after trimming with the help of its url. I am using https://github.com/a914-gowtham/android-video-trimmer for trimming my video and the updated uri after trimming is fine as I trying playing it in `exoplayer` and it works, the problem happens when I try to save it to external storage. I can see my file being saved to external storage as well but when I try to play it after saving via third party apps like vlc, mxplayer etc they throw error. So below is my code to save video after getting the uri

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var uri: Uri
    private lateinit var playerView: PlayerView

    private val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
    private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS =
        mutableListOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).toTypedArray()

    private var player: ExoPlayer? = null
    private var playWhenReady = true
    private var currentItem = 0
    private var playbackPosition = 0L

    private fun setUpPlayer(url: String){
        player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .build()
            .also { exoPlayer ->
                playerView.player = exoPlayer
                val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(url)
                exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
                exoPlayer.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
                exoPlayer.seekTo(currentItem, playbackPosition)
                exoPlayer.prepare()
            }
    }


    private val startForResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK &&
                result.data != null
            ) {
                uri = Uri.parse(TrimVideo.getTrimmedVideoPath(result.data))
                Log.i("TAG", "Trimmed path:: $uri")
                setUpPlayer(uri.toString())
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    lifecycleScope.launch {
                        val uri = saveVideoToExternalStorage()
                        Log.i("helloooo", "3487438734784387")
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Uri is $uri", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS,
                        REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
                    )
                }



            } else
                Log.i("TAG", "Trimmed path11111:: Errorr")
        }

    private val singleVideoPickerLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()) { videoUri ->
            TrimVideo.activity(videoUri.toString())
                .setHideSeekBar(true)
                .start(this, startForResult)
        }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        playerView = findViewById(R.id.playerview)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener {
            singleVideoPickerLauncher.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.VideoOnly))
        }


    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    Log.i("helloooo", "000000")
                    val uri = saveVideoToExternalStorage()
                    Log.i("helloooo", "1111111")
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Uri is $uri", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            } else {
                Log.i("TAG", "Permission denied")

            }
        }
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, it
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private suspend fun saveVideoToExternalStorage(): Uri? {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            Log.i("helloooo", "1")

            val videoCollection = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
            } else {
                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            }

            val file = uri.path?.let { File(it) }

            Log.i("helloooo", "2")
            val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                Log.i("helloooo", "3")

                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, uri.path)
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "${System.currentTimeMillis()}${file?.name}.mp4")

                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, "${System.currentTimeMillis()}${file?.name}.mp4")
                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
            }
            Log.i("helloooo", "4")
            val uri =
                contentResolver.insert(videoCollection, contentValues)
            Log.i("helloooo", "5 ${uri}")
            uri
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The insert() member inserts an entry in the media store data base and gives you an uri. Mostly it will not even create an empty file. So you are not using the obtained uri to save your downloaded data to it. You even are not downloading data.

Comment: `val file = uri.path?.let { File(it) }` ? What should that statement do? What is uri? You later declare an uri variable for insert().

Comment: uri is a variable I declared globally  and it is assigned to the value which the video trim library gives me once it is finish trimming the video, after which I run the above code. Anyways I have updated my code for more clarity

Comment: Do not use a global and a local variable with the same name. Very confusing.

Comment: `val uri = saveVideoToExternalStorage()` You are calling that function twice. Why? Also confusing.

Comment: What do you consider corrupted? What is the length of the resulting file? 0 bytes?

Comment: @blackapps yes it is 0 bytes and I am not able to play it with any video play

Comment: You really want to play an audio file with length of 0 bytes?

Comment: @blackapps No, firstly its a video file and that is my question why my file is getting corrupted after saving it?

Comment: You are not saving a file at all. I said that already in my first comment.

Comment: And it is not corrupted but has a length of zero bytes.

Comment: @blackapps can you tell then what I am doing wrong in my code?

Comment: That i also told you in my first comment: you are not saving your file.

Comment: `I can see my file being saved to external storage as well` No. It is not saved. Simply because there is no code to save your file. Just add code to save the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method to save the video in device's having android 10 or above.

Just pass the `file` and `display name`.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        @Throws(FileNotFoundException::class)
        fun Context.addVideoToGalleryAPI29(
            file: File,
            displayName: String,
            exportListener: VideoExportListener
        ) {
            val savePath = (Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
                    + File.separator + file.name)
            val cv = ContentValues()
            cv.put(
                MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
                        + File.separator + File(savePath).name
            )
            cv.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, "${displayName}.mp4")
            cv.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "${displayName}.mp4")
            cv.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
            cv.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
            cv.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis())
            cv.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
            val resolver = contentResolver
            val collection =
                MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
            val uriSavedVideo = resolver.insert(collection, cv)
            val pfd = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uriSavedVideo!!, "w")
            if (pfd != null) {
                try {
                    val out =
                        FileOutputStream(pfd.fileDescriptor)
                    val inputStream = FileInputStream(file)
                    val buf = ByteArray(8192)
                    var len: Int
                    while (inputStream.read(buf).also { len = it } > 0) {
                        out.write(buf, 0, len)
                    }
                    out.close()
                    inputStream.close()
                    pfd.close()
                    cv.clear()
                    cv.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                contentResolver.update(uriSavedVideo, cv, null, null)
            }
            exportListener.onVideoExported()
        }
```

Comment: What is VideoExportListener

Comment: Just an interface which will notify when the video file is saved. You can use your custom interface for that, too and get the event. Glad my answer helped.